# Android- Flurry getAsset("secHqImage").loadAssetIntoView () cause memory leak

Tags: android, flurry

```
FlurryAdNativeAsset secHqImageAsset = adNative.getAsset("secHqImage");
secHqImageAsset.getValue()
```

> The url points to either the local or remote resource, depending on how the ad >space is configured on dev.flurry.com
>
> Caching is enabled for the ad space - default setting: The SDK caches the assets onto the device before it declares the ad ready. The asset’s url in FlurryAdNativeAsset points to the local file (url contains the locator in the form file:// ) where the asset resides.
>
> Caching is not enabled for the ad space: The assets are available via https url. Calling loadAssetIntoView or getAssetView on the FlurryAdNativeAsset object loads the assets directly from the network and does not cache the assets.
>
> https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/android/

I cannot find anywhere in ad space to disable caching and I want to get the exactly remote link and load the image manually because keep using `getAsset("secHqImage").loadAssetIntoView()` will cause memory leak.

Is there any way to get the remote url link?

Comment: Hi, did you succeed in getting the remote url link?

Answer (score 0):

> FlurryAdNativeAsset secHqImageAsset = adNative.getAsset("secHqImage");

Now you have the FlurryAdNativeAsset.

> secHqImageAsset.getValue()

Should be replaced with:

```
String urlOfAsset = secHqImageAsset.getValue();
```

That should give you the URL string from where to get the asset. Once you get it, just use Android provided methods to load the Bitmap of the image.